# Can not install python in google VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, installation, virtual-machine

I can download the python-3.9.4-amd64, it prompt an window saying "Setup failed..... this installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator."

What does that mean?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add more details ? What version of Windows you're using ? If you provide reproduction steps I can try it on my end. Is that a "fresh" VM with no other software installed or you have other software running there ?

Comment: Hi @Wojtek_B, my google compute engine virtual machine edition is: windows server 2016 Datacenter, I have installed Anaconda, and another data vendor interface, that is all. I try to automate running python script however I can not install a Python, will appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Python is known to cause such issues on Windows systems.

Before you make any changes to your system [take a disk snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) in case something goes wrong. Particurarily if this is a production machine you don't want to be stuck without a working backup.

There are several ways to fix this and I recommend going through [How to fix “The installation is forbidden by system policy” error?](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-the-installation-is-forbidden-by-system-policy-error/) tutorial.

There are several ways, but in short you may try:

- fix your filesystem errors
- Edit Local Group Policy
- Check Local Security Settings
- Enable Windows Installer service
- make changed to Windows registry

I'm not going to copy-paste this but It looks like this is the way and since Python is explicitly mentioned in this tutorial then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for providing some help, but none of them worked....

Comment: Can you provide any logs, error messages, screenshots ?